# Focusing WebBrowser control in a C# application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `WebBrowser` control hosted in a windows `Form`. The control is used to display hyperlinks which get created at runtime. These links point to some HTML pages and PDF documents.

The problem is that when the form hosting the browser control is loaded, the focus is on the form. When the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is pressed, the focus does not shift to the first hyperlink. However, if I perform a mouse click on the control and then hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, the tab focus is now on the first hyper link. I tried using `Select()` on the `WebBrowser` control and then I called `Focus()`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas on how to set the tab focus on the first hyperlink at load? Thanks.

Cheers,
Harish

Answer (score 12):

I guess it might be because the focus is set before the page is fully loaded. Try this:

```
private void Go(string url)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus();
}
```

You could also automatically select the focus on the first link directly by getting the `HtmlElement` of that first link.

If the above doesn't work, you might want to check other parts of your code to see if anything else is capturing the focus. Try searching for `Select`, `Focus` and `ActiveControl` in your code.

Comment: This doesn't help in the current issue :(

Comment: If I may ask, which part doesn't help? The sample code that selects the WebBrowser control and allows the users to select the link with the TAB key? OR the part that explains you need to use the HtmlElement  of the first link to set focus on it? OR the part that ask to check whether anything else is capturing the focus? Do let me know which part isn't clear. I will explain further if required. Thank you.

Comment: @AshrafBashir, could you explain what the current issue is, that I failed to help?

Comment: The issue that doesn't work is the sample code that selects the WebBrowser control and allows the users to select the link with the TAB key

Answer (score 1):

Use `form.ShowDialog(form)` instead on `form.Show()`, then it will work !
where `form` is the running instance of your windows `Form`

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
private void txtAdres_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int licznik = 1;
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        string adres = txtAdres.Text;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(adres);
        licznik = 0;
    }
    if (licznik == 0)
    {
        webBrowser1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a normal scenario it should be sufficient for you to set the `TabIndex` of the `WebBrowser` control to **zero**. This way, when the form loads the control will be focused and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will iterate through the links.

Note that you should also change the `TabIndex` of the other controls on the form.

If this does not solve your problem, you need to add more detail on the complexity of the form hosting the control.