# Auto focusing a WebBrowser1 object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, focus

I have a TreeView with a list of URL's in it, and beside this TreeView, I have a WebBrowser1.

I'm trying to get it so that, when I click a link in the TreeView, focus is passed over to the WebBrowser so that with out any additional mouse clicks, I can start to scroll the newly loaded webpage.

I cannot seem to get this to work, no matter where in the code I add WebBrowser1.Focus()

I've tried adding this code in the following locations:

- WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted
- WebBrowser1_Navigating
- TreeView_MouseUp
- TreeView_Click
- TreeView_AfterSelect

None of these seem to hand over focus to the WebBrowser the way I had intended, I still have to click in the WebBrowser to gain access to the scroll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312755/focusing-webbrowser-control-in-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: Can you help me translate that? I can't read C#

Comment: This line is what you need: `webBrowser1.Document.Body.Focus()`

Comment: `webBrowser1.Document.Focus()` seems to work fine as well.

Comment: Hmm, so it only seems to work if the mouse is hovering over the webbrowser

Comment: Yes, just like a normal web browser. What exactly are you trying to do? You could always programmatically position the mouse cursor over the web browser control using something like `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Me.Location.X + Me.WebBrowser1.Location.X + 50, Me.Location.Y + Me.WebBrowser1.Location.Y + 50)`

Comment: Hmm, I guess I just never noticed as my personal webbrowser is always full screen, and this control one is a smaller size.